# Using transpose function in Excel

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I have a several text separated by `;`

```
   A
```

1;2;3;5;6;7;8;9;10 
11;12;13;14;15;16;17 
 
18;19;20;21

Column A has few text in each row 1,2,3 and so on separated by ';'

With the help of 'Text to Column' Option in 'Data' tab we are able to separate the same

Which will look something like this

A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
1   2   3   5   6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17
18  19  20  21

Now we have to manually copy all text and shift the same to same column

A
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21

Numbers shown are already example, it can be any text string.

We are doing manually and it takes lot of time as there are more than 100's of entry.

Is there any way to automate the same with the help of macro? Have been googling and trying but not yet successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by some VBA source code:

1. Add a button on your sheet
2. Double click on it
3. Add the following code:

   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim Counter As Integer
   Counter = 1
   Dim curString As String
   Dim whereComma As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 1 To 10
       curString = Cells(i, 1)
       whereComma = InStr(1, curString, ";", vbTextCompare)
       While InStr(whereComma, curString, ";", vbTextCompare) > 0
           Cells(Counter, 4) = Left(curString, whereComma - 1)
           Counter = Counter + 1
           curString = Right(curString, Len(curString) - whereComma)
       Wend
       Cells(Counter, 4) = curString
       Counter = Counter + 1
   Next I
   End Sub

End Sub

4. Click on button

You can see your result on column D

Answer (score 0):

This VBA will do what you want and output to column B:

```
Sub TransposeColumnA()
Dim X As Long
For X = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Resize(UBound(Split(Range("A" & X).Text, ";")) + 1, 1).Formula = Application.Transpose(Split(Range("A" & X).Text, ";"))
Next
End Sub
```